# Soapui method code too large

Tags: soapui

I have groovy script as one of the test step in soapUI with 1500 lines that contains multiple functions , while running 'method code too large ' error is thrown , is there a way to fix this by increasing memory settings in any of the soapui files ?

Comment: Are you using any templateEngine? relevant script that is causing error would help, can you edit the question to add the same?

Comment: A 1500 line method is insane. There must be a way you can split it into multiple methods. You can also make external groovy scripts with helper methods and then call them within your main groovy script to reduce the amount of code within it.

Comment: Yes , I divided the method functionality between multiple test steps , now it works fine